# Select a specific row on load swift tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableView where a user selects a row and a checkmark appears, these rows are put into an array. When the tableView loads how do I select specific rows. Here is what I found and tried but it didn't work:

```
let rowToSelect:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 1, section: 0);  

self.userTableView.selectRow(at: rowToSelect as IndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "select specific rows"? You want to select the checkmark for the previously selected rows?

Comment: I think the row is being selected, but you need the table view to be scrolled to the newly selected row by passing something other than `.none`. Check: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewscrollposition

Comment: @valcanaia, Yes, I have all the indexes stored in a global variable, I just want to hard code a cell selection if that makes sense

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed, Hi, when I change it to .top or .bottom I get this error :`2017-07-12 12:35:09.390507 SnapApp[417:97636] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).`

Comment: Check my answer. I posted a solution using the `selectRow` + `didSelectRow` and a solution using `cellForRow` supposing you have some UI component in you cell indicating the selection. If it doesn't solve your problem please let me know why so I can elaborate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you want to "check" the checkmark for the selected indexes you have in some variable. If this is what you want you can do this in your `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` method like:

```
myCell.checked = checkedIndexes[indexPath.row] ?? false
```

I'm supposing you have a custom cell with a `checked: Bool` variable so if you have the value in your `checkedIndexes` variable you set it, otherwise you set `false`.

**WARNING:** The `false` value is important because of the reuse of cells.

This is just a suggestion, you can do it any way you like it.

The `selectRow(at indexPath: IndexPath?, animated: Bool, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition)` method is just to select the row, it doesn't perform any action with logic related. For this to work you would have to implement `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` from the `UITableViewDelegate` with the code suggested before `myCell.checked = checkedIndexes[indexPath.row] ?? false`.